# Spring Boot Autowired a repo in a model

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, postconstruct

I have a model A and B and a relation model A_B

Now I want to have a getter in class A get something from class A-B
So I @Autowired the repo of A_B in the model A but it gives an error.

Is there any way to use a postconstruct kinda Autowire?

Here is my code:

```
@autowire IrepoA_B irepoA_B;

@PostConstruct
public boolean getVar() {
    return irepoA_B.getByTrackId(this.getId()).var();
}
```

How do I fix this so that he does not give the error:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>
> path resource........

Comment: Why `@PostConstruct` on a getter? It should be a `void` method. This might (and probably) will lead to too early querying of the database (before everything has been setup) and give you errors).

Comment: I hoped it would't init the autowired till it got used so according to my (flawed) logic it would only init the repo after starting the application

Comment: No... The `@PostConstruct` is called as soon as the object is created and dependencies have been satisfied. This could be even before a transactional proxy etc. have been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was in a whole different corner than I thought.

The problem was that it tried to make a column irepoA_B because it was used in an @Entity so I used the annotation @Transient. That fixed the error